Fetching upload file on flask and uploading it on my Deepgram AI
How do I get my uploaded file from flask to my AI?
from deepgram import Deepgram
import asyncio, json, os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect


dg_key = '6a5db8f6e43c35769ddce7a3523c792179b69f5c'
dg = Deepgram(dg_key)

MIMETYPE = 'mp3, wav'

DIRECTORY = 'UPLOAD_FOLDER'

options = {
    "punctuate": True,
    "diarize": True,
    "model": 'general',
    "tier": 'nova'
}


def main():
    audio_folder = os.listdir(DIRECTORY)
    for audio_file in audio_folder:
        if audio_file.endswith(MIMETYPE):
          with open(f"{DIRECTORY}/{audio_file}", "rb") as f:
              source = {"buffer": f, "mimetype":'audio/'+MIMETYPE}
              res = dg.transcription.sync_prerecorded(source, options)
              with open(f"./{audio_file[:-4]}.json", "w") as transcript:
                  json.dump(res, transcript, indent=4)
    return

main()

File variable on my flask code and setting as my root on my AI code.

(Disclosure: I work for Deepgram on these SDKs)
A few things stick out for me.

You question uses the legacy SDK, and our examples are all in the latest version which is not backwards compatible.
Are you aware you posted your API key onto a public website?

This is pulled straight from the examples on our Python SDK - I hope it helps. Things to note;

This should be a run-able file
Your API key will be read from your environment automatically
I've upgraded you from nova-general to nova-2-general
I've upgraded you from punctuate to smart_format which is our latest formatting feature.

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging
from deepgram.utils import verboselogs
from datetime import datetime
import httpx

from deepgram import (
    DeepgramClient,
    DeepgramClientOptions,
    PrerecordedOptions,
    FileSource,
)

load_dotenv()

AUDIO_FILE = "/path/to/your/file/file.wav"


def main():
    try:
        deepgram: DeepgramClient = DeepgramClient()

        with open(AUDIO_FILE, "rb") as file:
            buffer_data = file.read()

        payload: FileSource = {
            "buffer": buffer_data,
        }

        options: PrerecordedOptions = PrerecordedOptions(
            model="nova-2",
            smart_format=True,
            diarize=True,
        )

        response = deepgram.listen.prerecorded.v("1").transcribe_file(
            payload, options, timeout=httpx.Timeout(300.0, connect=10.0)
        )

        print(response.to_json(indent=4))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

